# Why is the URL 404 not found with Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have written a Django script that runs a Python parser to web s*e. I am sending the request to the Django script via AJAX. However, when the Ajax runs, it comes back as 404 not found for the URL. Why is this happening?

My code is below:

Ajax (with jQuery):

```
//send a `post` request up to AWS, and then 
//insert the data into the paths

$.post('/ca', function(data){
//evaluate the JSON
data = eval ("(" + data + ")");
//insert the vars into the DOM
var contentOne;
contentOne = data.bridge_time;
contentOne += 'min delay';
$('#timeone').html(contentOne);
var contentTwo;
contentTwo = data.tunnel_time;
contentTwo += 'min delay';
$('#timetwo').html(contentTwo);
//if this falls through, push an error.
var tunnel_time = data.tunnel_time;
var bridge_time = data.bridge_time;
var tunnel = document.getElementById('tunnel');
var bridge = document.getElementById('bridge');
var tunnelText = document.getElementById('timeone');
var bridgeText = document.getElementById('timetwo');
//algo for the changing icons. Kudos to Vito
if(tunnel_time<bridge_time){
  tunnel.src="tunnel3.png";
  bridge.src="bridge2r.png";
}else if( bridge_time<tunnel_time){
  bridge.src="bridge21.png";
  tunnel.src="tunnel2r.png";
}else{
  bridge.src="bridge2n.png";
  tunnel.src="tunnel2g.png";
}
  $.fail(function() {
alert("We're sorry. We are having an error. Check back later.");
});
});
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from views import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   (r'^/us', views.american_time),
                   (r'^/ca', views.canadian_time),
)
```

My `urls.py` and my `views.py` are in the same folder, if that makes any difference. They are just titled **views.py** and **urls.py**. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that ajax is totaly irrelevant here, you can leave just url with 404 response. I assume you get 404 when you open it in browser.
What is your web server, and how django is deployed there. Also relevant parts of settings would be useful to help

Comment: @alko for the webserver, we are using the Django/Apache/mod_wsgi installer from Bitnami, as we are on AWS.

Comment: from what I read it seems you ask wrong question. You should remove all ajax related stuff and ask why your django site do not work. I suggest to you to rewrite the question completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from views import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^/us/$', views.american_time),
     (r'^/ca/$', views.canadian_time),
)
```

Also you have to add the trailing slash in your JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, but it is still having the same problem. Could it have anything to do with the fact that I didn't start a Django project for this? We are using the Bitnami AWS installer, so I didn't create a Django project for this, just uploaded the files.

Comment: @Tjs do you have any working Django code, or is the Ajax script the only Django part in your site?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, can you clarify? I don't quite understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Tjs Er, not really, all I asked was whether you have other Django pages that work.

Comment: Sorry @DanielRoseman I misunderstood you. That is the only part of my site with Django.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this: there was an error in my urls.py. My system was having trouble with the `.defaults` that is was supposed to import from. Also, I didn't have a Django project set up, so It wouldn't import the views.